# using SafeAreaView with nativebase

Tags: react-native, native-base

Do we need use react-native SafeAreaView with nativebase. Or it is built in with container? Or just use SafeAreaView only without container?

```
<SafeAreaView> <--- is it needed?
  <Container>

  </Container>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:**

[Here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Container.js) you can find the code of NativeBase's container and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/SafeAreaView/SafeAreaView.js) you can find the code of react-native's SafeAreaView.

As you can see NativeBase's container is just a simple View, whereas the SafeAreaView is a little more complex, which makes sense if we take a look into the docs:

> The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later.

[react-native/docs/safeareaview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview)

**Answer**

> Or it is built in with container? Or just use SafeAreaView only
>   without container?

You can use them together, but you don't have to. As we see from the code, the container component does not implement the SafeAreaView by its own.

Comment: So i do need to wrap container with safeareaview as above to ensure safeareview in ios. am i right?

Comment: @vincentsty yes as you did in your example.

Comment: SafeAreaView is adding extra padding , do you know how to fix it????"?